# MySQL Error #1052 Column in from clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql

Having some issues with a query to my MySQL DB:

```
"SELECT event_id, area_name FROM tie_in.events LEFT JOIN tie_in.area USING (area_id)"
```

When I run this query against my DB it returns the error `#1052 - Column 'area_id' in from clause is ambiguous`.

I have other `LEFT JOIN`s in this query I just removed them for readability and they fetch fine.
Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Try `TABLE_NAME.area_id` (*where `TABLE_NAME` is the actual table name that contains the `area_id` column of course*).

Comment: Even when your queries don't encounter this issue, best practice is to qualify ALL column references with the name of the table or (preferably) an alias assigned to the table (see the answer from juergen d). This practice prevents this error from popping up later, in a query that was working, when someone adds a column to a table used by your query which matches the name of a column already referenced in your query.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error each time I separate my table and column with a period not sure what I am doing wrong.. @Darren

Comment: @velvetpuma It would help if you supplied the table schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If multiple tables have columns with the same name then you have to tell the DB which one to take by adding the table name in front of it

```
SELECT e.event_id, 
       a.area_name 
FROM tie_in.events e
LEFT JOIN tie_in.area a ON a.area_id = e.area_id
```

Comment: +1 One huge benefit of Following this pattern (i.e. qualifying ALL column references in EVERY query that references more than one table) is that it will prevent the "ambiguous column" error from popping up later, when someone adds a column to one of the tables used by a query, and the column name matches the name of a column already referenced in the query. (Adding a column to a table can "break" SQL statements that were working before, if this pattern isn't followed.) Another benefit is it's easier for a reader to decipher SQL; the reader may not "know" which columns are from which tables.

Comment: Great, this method works well, but now that i am formatting my query this way the syntax is kinda jargled on my datetime request: ` DATE_FORMAT(event_time, '%W %M %D at %l:%i%p') as event_time ` any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: nvm, I was simply placing it wrong. I figured it out. Thanks for the help!